# Crontab not executing python script

Tags: cron, python

I have this **root** cronjob:

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# 
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
# 
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').# 
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command
MAILTO=""
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /var/scripts/monitoring/load.py > /var/log/cron.log
```

The problem is that the cron log file is always empty, meaning the script is not executed, but when I run "/usr/bin/python3 /var/scripts/monitoring/load.py" manually in the CLI, it is all fine.

Comment: If you run other binaries/scripts from your `load.py` then you must provide full path to it.

Comment: Work your way through the linked duplicate it will likely help you solve your problem. If it does not, it will help you gather information that will help us help you. You should edit that information into your question. Note though that you are not gathering output from stderr which will likely contain the information required for you to solve this issue,